# xCode: Activating an IBAction from within a dynamically added subview

Tags: xcode, uiview, uibutton

I have a separate UIView class that constructs a simple footer bar that contains a UIButton.

```
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 50)];
    if (self) {
      int buttonHeight = self.frame.size.height;
      int buttonWidth = 70;
      int nextBtnPosX =0;
      int nextBtnPosY =0;


      self.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:254.0/255.0 green:193.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
      [self sendSubviewToBack:self];
      UIButton *nextBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      [nextBtn setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      nextBtn.frame = CGRectMake(nextBtnPosX, nextBtnPosY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
      [nextBtn addTarget:self.superview action:@selector(GoToNextPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   

      [self addSubview:nextBtn];

    }
    return self;
  }
```

I have several ViewControllers that then add this footer view class above to each view as a subview.

```
  UIView *newFooter = [[theFooter alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubview:newFooter];
```

Now the actual UIButton within the footer view needs to have its taget different for each viewController it is added to.

So I though it would be best to add the IBAction to the actual view controller then call this via the footer view.

But this is where I have come into a problem. How do I call the parent Controller to init the IBAction(GoToNextPage) from within the footer subview, from the addTarget?

Also would it be easier to have it all within the footer subview and pass in the target required, if so how else would this be done.

Comment: I have managed to prevent the app form crashing by adding this line of code on the actions section   [nextBtn addTarget:self.superview action... but this could mean its getting somewhere but just not calling my IBAction within the parent view...

Comment: I would suggest to use delegation for this kind of thing...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, any suggestion on this method cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough overview on what you should do.
This is how your UIView's header file should look

```
@protocol myViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)didPushButton:(id)sender;
@end

@interface UIViewController : UITableViewController
{
    __unsafe_unretained id <myViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <myViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Remember to `@synthesize delegate;` in your main file.

Finally in your main file, you will have an IBAction that receives the UIButton action.
Let's say that action is named buttonPushed.

Set that action to:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPushed:(id)sender
{
    if (delegate)
        [delegate didPushButton:sender];
}
```

Finally remember, that you need to set the delegate to each viewController you are using this viewController.

```
UIView *newFooter = [[theFooter alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:newFooter];
newFooter.delegate = self;
```